# Hacer una grid de imagenes con css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid-layout

Estoy haciendo una página web de viajes, estoy necesitando hacer una grid con imagenes como muestro en la imagen, las 3 imagenes del lado derecho tienen las mismas dimensiones, y las dos del lado izquierdo también son iguales entre sí.
Adjunto una imagen de como debería quedar y mi código.

```css
body {
  font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80%;
}
.text-image {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.subtitle-description {
  font-size: 12px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.logo-img{
  padding-left: 50px;
}

/*Barra de navegación*/
.nav-bar {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
.nav-bar__link, .nav-bar__link-active {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
}
.nav-bar__link-active {
  color: black;
}

.nav-bar li{
  padding: 0 20px;

}

/*Foto principal*/
.principal-cover {
  background-image: url(../img/Viajes_Hero.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-around;
  color: white;
  height: 600px;
}

.rectangle-info{
  margin-top: 200px;
}





/*Seccion Tendencias*/
.tendencies-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.tendencies-item {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 355px;
  height: 200px;
}
.logo-text {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
  margin-top: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  border: dashed;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  height: 120px;
}

/*Seccion Blog */
.container-blog{
  margin-top: 100px;
}


.all-blog-items{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 700px 370px;
  grid-template-rows: 430px;
}

.blog-item-big1{
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-image: url(../img/articulo_big_01.png);
  color: white;
}


.blog-item-big2{
  background-image: url(../img/articulo_big_02.png);
  border: 1px solid green;
  color: white;
}


.blog-item-small1{
 border: 1px solid red;
}

.blog-item-small2{
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.blog-item-small3{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ejercicio Aenima</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <header>
      <img class="logo-img" width="90px" class="logo" src="logo/logo_01.svg" alt="Logo">
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav-bar">
          <li>
            <a class="nav-bar__link-active" href="#">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav-bar__link" href="#">TENDENCIAS</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav-bar__link" href="#">BLOG</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container principal-cover">
      <div class="rectangle-info">
        <h1 class="text-image">AMÉRICA DEL SUR</h1>
        <h3 class="subtitle">Lugares maravillosos por America del Sur</h3>
        <p class="subtitle-description">Estos son algunos lugares que elijen la mayoría de los turistas que<br>visitan America del Sur</p>
      </div>
      <div class="logo-text">
        <img class="arrow-icon" src="iconos/arrow.svg" alt="logo">
        <p class="text-red">PRÓXIMA AVENTURA</p>
        <p class="text-white">Europa Meridional</p>
        <p class="text-description">Forman parte veinte países <br>ej.España,Francia,etc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-tendencies">
      <h3 class="title-tendencies">TENDENCIAS</h3>
      <div class="tendencies-group">
        <div class="tendencies-item">
          <img class="image-text" src="img/card_01.png" alt="card1">
          <h3>Montañas y magia</h3>
          <p>Aquí la descripción para<b>Montañas y magia</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="tendencies-item">
          <img src="img/card_02.png" alt="card2">
          <h3>Playa y sol</h3>
          <p>La descripción de <b> Playa y sol</b> debe ser esta</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tendencies-item">
          <img src="img/card_03.png" alt="card3">
          <h3>Nieve y aventura</h3>
          <p>Contiene la información de <b> Nieve y aventura</b></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-blog">
      <h3>BLOG</h3>
      <div class="all-blog-items">
        <div class="blog-item-big1"> 
          <h4>CIUDAD</h4>
          <h5>Artículo de puente</h5>
          <p>Un puente es una construcción que permite salvar un accidente geógrafico</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blog-item-big2"> 
          <h4>AVENTURA<h4>
          <h5>Artículo de aventura</h5>
          <p>Lugar poblado de árboles y arbustos con una importante densidad de</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blog-item-small1">
          <img src="img/articulo_small_01.png" alt="item1">
        </div>
        <div class="blog-item-small2">
          <img src="img/articulo_small_02.png" alt="item2">
        </div>
        <div class="blog-item-small3">
          <img src="img/articulo_small_03.png" alt="item3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partiendo que me apoye de este [proyecto](https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.com/) desarrollado por **Sara Drasner** para generar la estructura de la grilla buscada quedando de este modo:

```html
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .container-blog {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
  }
  .container-blog__article {
    background-color: tomato;
  }
  .first {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 3 / span 1;
  }
  .second {
    grid-area: 4 / 1 / span 3 / span 1;
  }
  .three {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / span 2 / span 1;
  }
  .four {
    grid-area: 3 / 2 / span 2 / span 1;
  }
  .five {
    grid-area: 5 / 2 / span 2 / span 1;
  }
  .container-blog-parrafo {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: crimson;
    color: white;
  }
</style>
<section class="container-blog">
  <article class="container-blog__article first">
    <p class="container-blog-parrafo">
      Elemento 1
    </p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati quasi debitis officiis molestiae repellat consequuntur, optio vitae porro amet cumque minus et beatae vel modi qui provident, doloremque similique quis.
  </article>
  <article class="container-blog__article second">
    <p class="container-blog-parrafo">
      Elemento 2
    </p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero vel, omnis distinctio vitae eos autem. Et molestias ipsam eum delectus ea illum, quas modi unde amet, tempora soluta nihil qui.
  </article>
  <article class="container-blog__article three">
    <p class="container-blog-parrafo">
      Elemento 3
    </p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae libero, id ab adipisci ipsum dolorem dolores repellendus quia consequatur voluptates eos cum corporis, veniam reprehenderit, quas perferendis nesciunt deleniti vero.
  </article>
  <article class="container-blog__article four">
    <p class="container-blog-parrafo">
      Elemento 4
    </p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores excepturi nulla quos recusandae deserunt, nobis commodi nisi facilis sed at laudantium voluptatem cupiditate perferendis porro mollitia. Odit, eius eos obcaecati?
  </article>
  <article class="container-blog__article five">
    <p class="container-blog-parrafo">
      Elemento 5
    </p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque possimus sint nulla ad neque necessitatibus ullam asperiores dolores a, cum adipisci vel quasi repellat molestias dignissimos quas nam cupiditate atque.
  </article>
</section>
```

**Explicación**

Lo que hace `grid-area` es indicar para la **`class=first`** y para la **`class=second`**

- incia en la fila 1 y en la columna 1
- ocupa 3 filas y de ancho 1 columna
- inicia en la fila 4 y en la columna 1
- ocupa 3 filas y de ancho 1 columna

Para la **`class=three`**

- inicia en la fila 1 y en la columna 2
- ocupa 2 filas y de ancho 1 columna

Para la **`class=four`**

- inicia en la fila 3 y en la columna 2
- ocupa 2 filas y de ancho 1 columna

Para la **`class=five`**

- inicia en la fila 5 y en la columna 2
- ocupa 2 filas y de ancho 1 columna

> Divido mi grilla en 2 columnas y en seis filas de ancho automático mediante la medida de **`fr`**

Como punto adicional, te recomiendo leer [la especificación de la W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics.html#semantics) respecto a las etiquetas y su semántica al momento de que construyas tu *layout* para que tengas mas claro como aplicarlos a tu desarrollo.